# Passing anonymous functions through jQuery event call without eventData

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

Given an `<input id="foo">` element, I want to call an *existing* function on blur and pass an anonymous callback to it.

Case 1, simple function call:

```
function bar(){
    alert("I am");
}

$("#foo").blur(bar); //Works fine
```

Case 2, passing arguments/function:

```
$("#foo").bind("blur", {func: function(){console.log("I am apple")}}, bar);

function bar(event){
    event.data.func(); //Works fine
};
```

Problem with case 2 is that I'd like to have `bar()` as a generic function called by more than blur, in which case I would be passing anonymous function directly, not "baked" into a data object. So ideally like this:

```
function bar(callback){
    //Do stuff
    callback();
}

bar(function(){console.log("Hello Earth")}); //Works

$("#foo").blur(bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")})); //Doesn't work
```

Last line doesn't work as function gets executed directly, but it's an example of what I would like to achieve. I guess I possibly could make some typeof checks in `bar()` to determine what I am receiving, but I wanted to ask if there's a cleaner way to pass anonymous function on blur, instead of changing `bar()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function bar(callback){
    //Do stuff
    callback();
}

bar(function(){console.log("Hello Earth")}); //Works

$("#foo").blur(bar.bind(this,function(){console.log("Hello world")})); //Will work
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Although it was missing an additional parenthesis before semicolon, I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 4):

> ...I wanted to ask if there's a cleaner way to pass anonymous function on blur, instead of changing `bar()`.

Not sure quite what you mean by that, you will have to either change `bar` or wrap `bar`.

#### Changing it:

Make `bar` a handler *generator* rather than a direct handler:

```
function bar(callback) {
    return function(e) {
        // You could use `e` (the event) here and/or pass it on to the callback
        callback();
        // You might use the callback's return, e.g.:
        // return callback();
        // ...if you wanted it to be able to `return false`
    };
}
```

Now, `bar` returns an event handler that will call the callback (in addition, presumably, to doing something of its own; otherwise, it's a bit pointless and you'd just pass the callback directly).

Usage:

```
$("#foo").blur(bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")}));
```

#### Wrapping it

If you literally mean you don't want to change bar, you'll need to *wrap* it:

```
function wrap(f, callback) {
    return function() {
        // You could call `callback` here instead of later if you like

        // Call the original function passing along the `this` and
        // arguments we received (`arguments` isn't pseudo-code, it's
        // a pseudo-array JavaScript creates for you), get its return value
        var retval = f.apply(this, arguments);

        // Call the callback
        callback();

        // Return the original function's return value
        return retval;
    };
}
```

If you want to avoid letting errors thrown by `callback` to make it to the event mechanism, you can wrap it in a `try`/`catch`.

Usage:

```
$("#foo").blur(wrap(bar, function(){console.log("Hello world")}));
```

Comment: So the question is: "can I do this without changing `bar`?", and the most voted answer is "just change `bar`"?

Comment: @pawel: I kinda missed that bit at the end of about not changing `bar`. :-| You're right, it's there. I suspect the OP doesn't mean not changing it at all, but you're right, it's there.

Comment: @pawel: I forgot to say "thank you" above. Thank you. :-) I've fixed the answer now.

Comment: No problem, but I still think @Piyush.kapoor solution using `.bind` for partial application looks cleaner ;)

Comment: @pawel: But it changes `bar`. Ah, I guess it depends which `bar` you're talking about.

Comment: Indeed, as @pawel said, it was strongly preferable for me not to change the `bar` function I am calling, so `.bind` solution is a better fit. But thank you for suggesting the handler generator approach, I've learned something new, and it seems better practice for future.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it and return it as an anonymous function:

```
function bar(callback){
    return function() {
        callback();
    }
}

// direct
bar(function(){console.log("Hello Earth")})();

// as callback
$("#foo").blur(bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function bar(){
    alert("I am blur");
}

$("#foo").bind('blur',bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Last line doesn't work as function gets executed directly

```
$("#foo").blur(bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")}));
```

On the last line you're passing the *result* of `bar` to the `blur()` function, not bar itself, it's the same as:

```
var result = bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")});
$("#foo").blur(result);
```

The standard method is to wrap this in an anon function:

```
$("#foo").blur(function() { bar(function(){console.log("Hello world")}) });
```

This means there are no changes to your other existing functions, as per the question requirement: "*instead of changing bar()*"